# Nested class functions access

Tags: c++, class, nested

I am having a little problem access Nested Class functions.
I created a function in the nested class that return one of the fields of the nested class (class B) , and I want use this field in Class A functions.
It looks like this:

```
class A{
int x,y,z;

  class B{
  public:
  char* name;
  char* ReturnName();
  };
public:

void function1();
};

//functions
char* A::B::ReturnName(){
     return this->Name;
}
//main problem:
void A::function1(){
     char* NAME=A::B::ReturnName();
}
```

how do I access to ReturnName(); funtion (from class B)  inside a function of Class A?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: The way you are using it right now - is like ReturnName() is a static function. You cannot do this. ReturnName() is non-static and need an instance of class A::B in order to be used.

Comment: can you show me how it supposed to be? thanks alot!

Comment: one way is the following: https://godbolt.org/g/UoT6hq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create object  of `class A::B` to call `ReturnName()`.

```
//functions
char* A::B::ReturnName(){
     return this->name;
}
//main problem:
void A::function1(){
    B *b  = new B();
     char* NAME = b->ReturnName();
}
```

Comment: You should avoid allocating objects using `new` in C++ (unless there is a good reason for it). Just write `B b; char* NAME=b.ReturnName();`

Comment: that is true. Bottom line was to create object to call ReturnName().